# Is it possible to install MySQL Server 5.7 on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: software-installation, mysql, 19.10

Is it possible to install MySQL Server 5.7 on Ubuntu 19.10? If yes, how?

Answer (score 14):

MySQL server 5.7 isn't available in the repositories of Eoan Ermine (19.10) but is available in Bionic Beaver (18.04) from Ubuntu's official repostories as well as MySQL's. You can install MySQL Server 5.7 on Eoan using Bionic's repository.

1. To use MySQL's repository for Ubuntu 18.04

   - First of all create a new text file with sudo privileges:

     ```
     sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
     ```
   - Add these lines:

     ```
     deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-apt-config
     deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7
     deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools
     #deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools-preview
     deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7
     ```

     You can comment/uncomment the repository according to the packages required. Save and exit using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd>.
     Then run

     ```
     sudo apt update
     ```
   - You'll get an error, like

     ```
     Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
       The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <some key value>
     ```
   - Add this key using

     ```
     sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <key value>
     ```
   - Update and check which version of MySQL 5.7 is currently available

     ```
     sudo apt update
     apt-cache policy mysql-server
     ```

     At the time of writing this answer, 5.7.29-1ubuntu18.04 was available.
   - Install the required MySQL version.

     ```
     sudo apt install mysql-server=5.7.29-1ubuntu18.04
     ```

   **Note:** For some reasons in my installation APT wasn't installing mysql-client while installing MySQL Server 5.7 which is a dependency of MySQL Community Server which in turn is a dependency of MySQL Server due to which dependency issues occured. To get out of that I needed to install MySQL client using APT first

   ```
   sudo apt install mysql-client=5.7.29-1ubuntu18.04
   ```
2. To install using Ubuntu's repositories, add Ubuntu 18.04's official repositories, update the cache and instal MySQL 5.7. Fo that run:

   ```
   echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security restricted main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic.list
   sudo apt update
   apt-cache policy mysql-server
   sudo apt install mysql-server=5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
   ```

   I'd recommend to delete Bionic's repository after the installation since having repository information of other releases can sometime break the installation. To do that run

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic.list
   ```

Comment: at present the mysql version on that repository is: 5.7.29-1ubuntu18.04

Comment: The second method leaves the user with no way to get security updates, right?

Comment: @sarnold Not really. Since in second method, MySQL was actually installed using Bionic's security packages sources. Addition of software sources of some other release can cause conflict of packages that are also in the current release. Here, only those sources were removed which were added solely for the purpose of installing MySQL to avoid future conflicts. You'll still get security updates from Eoan's repository.

Comment: @Kulfy, I'm sorry, I should have been more clear -- your second method will leave the user with no way to receive mysql security updates, correct? There's no mysql-5.7 source package for eoan: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7

Comment: @sarnold True that.

Comment: gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure

Comment: @AnkitSinghaniya Are you behind some firewall?

Comment: @Kulfy not but I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @AnkitSinghaniya I retried adding the key on 20.04 using `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8C718D3B5072E1F5` and it succeeded. Try using port 80, i.e. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8C718D3B5072E1F5`

Comment: at present my sql version on the above repo update to mysql-server=5.7.31-1ubuntu18.04

Answer (score 4):

Adding onto Kulfy's answer. If you want to prevent the package from being updated back to MySQL 8+, create a file named `mysql` at `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`.

In that file place the following contents

```
Package: mysql-server
Pin: version 5.7.29-1ubuntu18.04
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: mysql-client
Pin: version 5.7.29-1ubuntu18.04
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: mysql-community-server
Pin: version 5.7.29-1ubuntu18.04
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: mysql-community-client
Pin: version 5.7.29-1ubuntu18.04
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

This will prevent `apt upgrade` from upgrading MySQL back to version 8.

**NOTE:** The version you use may be different, as of 2/12/2020 the version is `5.7.29-1ubuntu18.04`. To get the version run `apt list --installed | grep -E 'mysql-(client|server)'`.

Answer (score 2):

Extending on the answers of both Kulfy and NSwanson7, the installation can be fixed to version 5.7.*. No need to specify an exact version.

1. Pin the version of mysql-client and mysql-server to 5.7*. For this create the file /etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql with content

   ```
   Package: mysql-server
   Pin: version 5.7*
   Pin-Priority: 1001

   Package: mysql-client
   Pin: version 5.7*
   Pin-Priority: 1001
   ```
2. Add repositories from Ubuntu 18.04. For this create file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list with content

   ```
   deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-apt-config
   deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7
   deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools
   deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7
   ```
3. Update repos and install

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install mysql-client mysql-server
   ```

or use the below script:

```
echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-apt-config"  | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7"  | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools"  | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
echo "deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-5.7"  | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list

echo "Package: mysql-server" | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql
echo "Pin: version 5.7*" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql
echo "Pin-Priority: 1001" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql
echo "" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql
echo "Package: mysql-client" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql
echo "Pin: version 5.7*" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql
echo "Pin-Priority: 1001" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql

sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install mysql-server mysql-client
```